# How to implement "keep me logged in" in asp.net membership?

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP.NET Membership Provider, while logging In I am checking checkbox "Keep me logged in".
Next time when run application (considering I have not logged out previously), first it comes to Login Page Load(where it checks for **IsAuthenticated**) and master page and loads home page

I have checked **IsAuthenticated** property in Page Load of Login page, if authenticated navigate to Homepage.

But I do not want to go to Login Page's Page Load unnecessarily and check there. Is there any other way to implement this without going to page Load of Login Page